# Why doesn't my JS update my data-theme back?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive

I want to have a button inside my navbar (`ul li`) that can toggle between `theme=light` and `theme=dark`. However, only activating dark mode works.

**Code:**

I created a button
    `<li><a href="#" onclick="darkMode()"><i class="fas fa-moon"></i></a></li>`, with a JS function

```js
function darkMode () {
    var isOn = false;
    if(Boolean(isOn) === false) {
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
        var isOn = true;
    }
    else if(Boolean(isOn) === true) {
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
        var isOn = false;
    }
}
```

and my css looks like this:

```css
:root, [data-theme="light"] {
  --bg-color: #ffffff;
  --bg-color-inv: #000000;
  --outline-color: #000000;
  --text-primary: #000000;
  --text-primary-inv: #ffffff;
  --text-secondary: #a4a4a4;
  --text-secondary-hover: #000000;
  --chivo: 'Chivo', sans-serif;
}

[data-theme="dark"] {
  --bg-color: #121212;
  --bg-color-inv: #ffffff;
  --outline-color: #ffffff;
  --text-primary: #ffffff;
  --text-primary-inv: #000000;
  --text-secondary: #5b5b5b;
  --text-secondary-hover: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Because each time the function invokes, `isOn` is set to false. Variables which are changing should be assigned before function, not inside function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.** You start the function by setting the `isOn` to `false`. so `Boolean(isOn) === false` alwaeys return `true`. you should init the `isOn` variable outside the function

**2** Why you convert the `isOn` to boolean? it's already boolean type..

**3** You not really need `else if`.. if it is not false it is true..

**4.** as mentioned in the comment below, not need reinitiate the `isOn` inside the `if else`

```
var isOn = false;

function darkMode () {
    if(!isOn) {
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
        isOn = true;
    }
    else {
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
        isOn = false;
    }
}
```

in even more elegant way, you can do:

```
var isOn = false;

function darkMode () {

    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', ['dark', 'light'][+isOn]);
    isOn = !isOn;

}
```

**explanation**

`+isOn` convert it to number, so `true` become `1` and `false` become `0`.
Then you use this number as index to choose `dark` or `light` accordingly.

`isOn=!isOn` flip the current value of `isOn` - `true` become `false` and `false` become `true`